# How to set default action dynamically in Yii

Tags: yii, action, default

i want to change default action of a controller depends on which user is logged in.
Ex. There are two users in my site : publisher and author and i want to set publisher action as default action when a publisher is logged in, and same for author.

what should i do? when can I check my roles and set their relevant actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to do this would be setting the [`defaultAction` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#defaultAction-detail) in your controller's [`init()` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail). Somewhat like this:

```
<?php
class MyAwesomeController extends Controller{ // or extends CController depending on your code
    public function init(){
        parent::init(); // no need for this call if you don't have anything in your parent init() 

        if(array_key_exists('RolePublisher', Yii::app()->authManager->getRoles(Yii::app()->user->id)))
            $this->defaultAction='publisher'; // name of your action

        else if (array_key_exists('RoleAuthor', Yii::app()->authManager->getRoles(Yii::app()->user->id)))
            $this->defaultAction='author'; // name of your action
    }
    // ... rest of your code
}
?>
```

Check out [CAuthManager's `getRoles()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAuthManager#getRoles-detail), to see that the returned array will have format of `'role'=>CAuthItem object`, which is why i'm checking with `array_key_exists()`.

Incase you don't know, the action name will be only the name without the action part, for example if you have `public function actionPublisher(){...}` then action name should be: `publisher`.

Comment: if you have a different meaning of role,(i.e if not using yii's rbac), then you'll have to modify the check to use your meaning of role.

Answer (score 1):

Another, simpler, thing you can do is keep the default action the same, but that default action simply calls an additional action function depending on what kind of user is logged in. So for example you have the indexAction function conditionally calling `this->userAction` or  `this->publisherAction` depending on the check for who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save "first user page" in user table. And when a user is authenticated, you can load this page from database. Where you can do this? I think best place is UserIdentity class. After that, you could get this value in SiteController::actionLogin();

You can get or set "first page" value:

```
            if (null === $user->first_page) {
                $firstPage = 'site/index';
            } else {
                $firstPage = $user->first_page;
            }
```

This is a complete class:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));
        if ($user === null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if ($user->password !== $user->encrypt($this->password)) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->_id = $user->id;

            if (null === $user->first_page) {
                $firstPage = 'site/index';
            } else {
                $firstPage = $user->first_page;
            }

            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}



/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->first_page);
    }

    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Also, you can just write right code only in this file. In SiteController file.

Comment: This is a good idea for redirecting user to their address. But i don't need to save their address to DB, I can assign address to each role in userIdentity. Thank you so much.